# How to include current element within result of Element.select?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, prototypejs

Is it possible to add the current element as an entry to the result of `Element.select`?

Background: I want to apply a specific class name to an element and some of its children. So something like `myElem.select('this, .childElements').invoke('addClassName', 'alice')` would be cool - but, of course, **this** isn't a valid keyword here.

*<sub>[Prototype.js Docs for Element.select](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/select/)</sub>*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that behavior is not the target of the `select()` method. However you can get the results you are looking for by going up to `myElem` parent element.

```
myElem.up().select('.childElements, .parentElement').invoke('addClassName','alice')
```